# Como puedo aplicar un degradado a un StyleBoxFlat en Godot?

Tags: godot-engine

Pasa que tengo un nodo "Button" en mi escena y en los Styles de la propiedad "Theme Overrides" le agregue un StyleBoxTexture para agregar un degradado al boton pero me topo con que el StyleBoxTexture no tiene opciones para redondear bordes. Por otro lado, el StyleBoxFlat si tiene dicha propiedad para redondear bordes pero no tiene para agregar un degradado, solo puedo usar un color solido.
Probe el uso de shader para aplicar el degradado al "Button" en si, pero el shader me tapa el texto e icono del "Button".

Intente de todo y se me acabaron las ideas jaja, si alguien tiene una solucion le pido de favor si puede compartirla

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

Dos funciones que crean y establecen los valores del degradado, para cuando esta en estado normal y cuando se pone el cursor sobre el.

[image: Dos funciones que crean y establecen los valores del degradado]

[En el StyleBoxFlat tiene la opción "Corner Radius"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyFkK.png)

[image: En el StyleBoxTexture si tiene la opcion de degradado pero no de redondear bordes]

Comment: Hola Gael Geb, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son. mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.